# Duplicating 1st three rows in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

I wanted to duplicate the rows in SQL 3 times, below is the format

Eg of query when run:-

[image]

Desired O/P:-

[image]

Pls note, count value should get updated for every new duplicate value

How should I write my SQL query here?

Comment: _count value should get updated for every new duplicate value_ Yet your desired output shows no change in "count value". "Pls note" is not a useful comment to make since no one but YOU knows what the logic and desired outcome is.

Comment: Added the same,thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this

```
select t.* , dups.id
from yourtable t
cross apply (values (1) , (2) , (3)) dups(id) 
order by dups.id , name , lastname
```

Comment: you just need to include id from dups table to the select to show the count column

Comment: Thanks for that, I want my count to be changed for every new duplicate value, which is not the case in the query. Eg John Mark and Robin counts should be 1 as they are the original value, but John is getting iterated 3 times with the same values of count

Comment: @RohanJacob I don't think so , I think they are not just sorted ,  you need to sort them by dups.id

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is `cross join`:

```
select t.*
from t cross join
     (values (1), (2), (3)) v(n);
```

Comment: Thanks for that Gordan, I want my count to be changed for every new duplicate value, which is not the case in the query. Eg John Mark and Robin coun'ts should be 1 as they are the original value, but John is getting iterated 3 times with same values of count.